# Shortening a Javascript if-else structure

Tags: javascript

The code I have is:

```
 var level = function (d) {
    if (value(d) > median + stdev) {
        return 1;
    } else if (value(d) > median) {
        return 2;
    } else if (value(d) > median - stdev) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
 };
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: This is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: wondering about ternary operator. but how here ?

Comment: a nested ternary operator seems possible, though will be harder to read

Comment: What are your criteria for "nicer"? Is there a reason you are re-evaluating value(d) up to three times?

Comment: use a switch statement!

Comment: That is easy to read and understand. Why would you need to modify it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course calling `value(d)` multiple times is something you can avoid.

Also you can shorten a little using the [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry):

```
  var level = function (d) {
    //
    //               -std    median  +std
    // ----------------|-------|-------|------------------
    // 4444444444444444 3333333 2222222 111111111111111111
    //
    var i = Math.floor((median - value(d)) / stddev) + 3;
    return Math.max(1, Math.min(4, i));
  };
```

Probably not a good idea for a real project however... I didn't test but I wouldn't be surprised to find this code slower than the original in your question and for sure I find it harder to maintain.

Note that excluding one-shot throwaway scripts normally code is written once and read many times (for maintenance like improvements or debugging), thus "easier to read" is normally much more important than "easier to write".

When shorter means "easier to read" is a good thing, when it starts meaning "harder to read" it's not.

Comment: awesome man! very nice documentation/representation, I remember you from python answer.

Comment: what is "symmetry" ? :)

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark: The simplification comes from the fact that the two intervals are equal, so dividing the difference between the value and the median by the width of the interval you already get a numeric integer code that only needs clamping.

Comment: the ascii art is nice, but i do not see how the code is "nicer". it is more "clever" and fewer lines, but it uses division and functions from Math, and generally does not work with a nominal scale ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Nominal_scale ). it is not faster to execute. refactoring the code is no longer straight forward, e.g. if you want other values/another type for the values or just include other/more cases... this is code golf ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf ), but no improvement in code quality.

Comment: @mnagel: I agree. Please double-check what is the question title.

Comment: @6502: the title and the closing request in the question differ somewhat, and everyone concentrated on "short" instead of "nice". this might or might not be what the original author wanted, i cannot say. i find your answer insightful, but i would not apply the refactoring to my code (i would copy the docstring, though). my comment provides concrete arguments about the problematic aspects i see and it is intended to make you think what you care about in your code. altogether, this is a good answer imho, but not an answer i wanted to leave without a comment.

Comment: I do not want to downvote this answer, because that is kind of what was asked for, but this is still **very** bad advice on every level. It is (probably) slower and near unmaintainable.

Comment: @Chronial: I agree. Except for the multiple calls to `value(...)` I'd keep the original code.

Answer (score 7):

To complete the set, here is the `switch` way referenced by @austin :

```
var level = function (d) {
  var d = value(d) - median;
  switch (true) {
  case d > stdev : return 1;
  case d > 0:      return 2;
  case d > -stdev: return 3;
  default:         return 4;
  }
};
```

Comment: is this allow in case `< == >` ? if yes then +, else I will come back to down-vote you :)

Comment: I am confident that you will have no need to down vote. It is a surprising construct when you first see it. The definition of `case` is actually an expression not a literal value. This can be used to advantage in sometimes.

Comment: I am a c programmer, its really surprising to me!, is it only possible in JavaScript? or New versions of Java allows this too? Because once back in time I was wondering that case can be strings in Java.

Comment: It is certainly easier to do in an interpretive language like JavaScript. As you know in C the case value needs to be a literal integer value. A quick check shows that in Java the case values must be integer or string constants.

Comment: I've seen this in other languages as well, though I've heard that it's a performance killer (at least in JavaScript).  If this has to be run many times, your original if/else is probably faster.  I wish I could do this in other languages, but none of the languages I use regularly (C/C++/C#/Java) allow it.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is nicer, but I would not recommend using it in production as it is kind of confusing:

```
4 - [median + stdev, median, median - stdev].filter(function(e, i, a) {
    return value(d) > e;
}).length
```

Comment: yeah but +1 for surely using the least amount of bytes to store on my HD

Comment: @jenson-button-event: Those are the most important bytes ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote but for sure this and @6502 answers are a bit far to be immediately understandable. ;D

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the difference between the value and the median, which makes the comparisons simpler:

```
function level(d) {
  var n = value(d) - median;
  if (n > stdev) {
    return 1;
  } else if (n > 0) {
    return 2;
  } else if (n > -stdev) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 4;
  }
};
```

You can also write it using the conditional operator instead of `if` statements:

```
function level(d) {
  var n = value(d) - median;
  return n > stdev ? 1 :
    n > 0 ? 2 :
    n > -stdev ? 3 :
    4;
  }
};
```

Whether this is nicer or not is a matter of taste, but it's shorter.

Answer (score 2):

"nicer" way? No, not really.

Alternate way(s) - yes, plentiful.

One possibility is storing the condition and result in an array

```
var levelFunctions = [
  { func: function(d){ return value(d) > median + stdev; }, val:1},
  { func: function(d){ return value(d) > median ; }, val:2},
  { func: function(d){ return value(d) > median - stdev; }, val:3},
  { func: function(d){ return true; }, val:4}
];
```

Then just enumerating that list as part of the function

```
var level = function (d) {
    for(var i=0;i<levelFunctions.length;i++){
       if(levelFunctions[i].func(d))
           return levelFunctions[i].val;
    }
 };
```

A bit easy to extend than your original, but by *[diety]* its ugly as sin!

Comment: If you really wanted to use an array, you should use one like @amberlamps did.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much room for improvements which could guarantee the same readability of the starting case. If you are really returning integers, and they aren't there just for the sake of this example, I would suggest you to return something more meaningful.

You could for sure compute `value(d)` just once

```
var level = function (d) {
  var dValue = value(d);
  if (dValue > median + stdev) {
    return 1;
  } else if (dValue > median) {
    return 2;
  } else if (dValue > median - stdev) {
    return 3;
  } else {
   return 4;
  }
};
```

Also, you might want to avoid multiple returns, or maybe you don't, for me they're the same, each has advanges/disadvantages:

```
var level = function (d) {
  var dValue = value(d),
      code = 4;
  if (dValue > median + stdev) {
    code = 1;
  } else if (dValue > median) {
    code = 2;
  } else if (dValue > median - stdev) {
    code = 3;
  } 
  return code;
};
```

If you assign a meaningful name to `code` you are giving even more information to the guy who is reading your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to avoid multiple calls to `value`:

```
function level(d) {
    var diff = value(d) - median;
    if (diff > 0) {
        if (diff > stdev)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    else
        if (diff > -stdev)
            return 3;
        else
            return 4;
}
```

Also I've nested the if-else-statements in a (hopefully) more meaningful structure - that depends on your usecase though. Might be more helpful if you returned values like `-2`, `-1`, `1` and `2` instead or something. A ternary operator could save you some writing, but it's not necessarily getting clearer.

Alternatively, some maths could help you:

```
function level(d) {
    var diff = value(d) - median;
    return 2 + (diff > 0 ? -.5 : .5) * (Math.abs(diff) > stdev ? 3 : 1);
}
```

Though it leads to `3` instead of `4` in case `value(d) === median-stdev`. See @6502's answer on how to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Well if we're going for short, creative solutions...

```
var level = function(d){
    d = value(d);
    return +(d<=median+stdev)+ +(d<=median)+ +(d<=median-stdev) + 1
}
```

Comment: i find this solution quite 'creative'

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement ([Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)).

*Edit:* If you think it's impossible to do ranges in a switch statement, here's an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than/6666246#6666246).

Comment: Not (easily) for greater-than/less-than checks.

Comment: I don't think a 30 times slower technique is particularly "nice".

Comment: You should include a code snippet to show how that can be used here. It's a good technique that you pointed to.

Comment: It will be longer whereas the OP wanted shorter. It is also clever which can be considered a bad thing outside StackOverflow answers

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't remove the if/else structure but makes the code a bit cleaner:

```
var level = function (d) {
    var delta = value(d) - median;
    if (delta > stdev) {
        return 1;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if (delta > -stdev) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
 };
```

It has the added benefit of calling `value(d)` only once.

Answer (score 1):

Another option — ignoring the usefulness of maths in this instance — is to do away with the if statements altogether. I generally prefer this approach to that of using ternary operators. I tend to think this is more readable than having multiple if/else constructs (for simple situations), but that is only because I am versed in the ways of JavaScript's logical operators. I can fully understand how odd it might look to those learning, or people who code in strange and foreign languages where `1 && 3 === TRUE` and not `3`

```
var level = function (d) {
  d = value(d);
  return ((d > median + stdev) && 1) 
      || ((d > median)         && 2) 
      || ((d > median - stdev) && 3)
      || 4
  ;
}
```

A further possible optimisation — unique to this question — would be to remove `median` from the comparisons, however, this would most likely affect the readability:

```
var level = function (d) {
  d = value(d) - median;
  return ((d > + stdev) && 1) 
      || ((d > 0)       && 2) 
      || ((d > - stdev) && 3)
      || 4
  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var level = function(d){
    var n = value(d) - median, values = [];
    values[stdev]  = 1;
    values[0]      = 2;
    values[-stdev] = 3;
    return values[n] ? values[n] : 4;
};
```

`values` could be pulled out of the function scope if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't touch the code.

There are many posted codes here, but still yours is the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this tho ...**

```
  var reduceCalcVal=value(d);   //reduce repeated calculation
  var cheats=new Array( reduceCalcVal > median + stdev
    ,reduceCalcVal  > median, reduceCalcVal > median - stdev);
    n=(cheats.indexOf(true)==-1)?4:cheats.indexOf(true)+1;
    alert(n)
```

Comment: More succinctly :    d = value(d) - median;
   return [d > stdev, d > median, d > -stdev, true].indexOf (true) + 1;