# javascript function to increment array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, increment

I am using a function to increment values in an array depending on the value passed to it.

```
function depth(x) {
    var dep = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    if (x < 10) {
        var deps = dep[0];
        dep[0] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 10 && x < 20) {
        var deps = dep[1];
        dep[1] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 20 && x < 30) {
        var deps = dep[2];
        dep[2] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 30 && x < 40) {
        var deps = dep[3];
        dep[3] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 40 && x < 50) {
        var dep2 = dep[4];
        dep[4] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 50 && x < 60) {
        var deps = dep[5];
        dep[5] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 60 && x < 70) {
        var deps = dep[6];
        dep[6] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 70 && x < 80) {
        var deps = dep[7];
        dep[7] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 80 && x < 90) {
        var deps = dep[8];
        dep[8] = dep2 + 1;

    } else if (x >= 90 && x < 100) {
        var deps = dep[9];
        dep[9] = dep2 + 1;

    } else if (x >= 100 && x < 110) {
        var deps = dep[10];
        dep[10] = deps + 1;


    } else if (x >= 110 && x < 120) {
        var deps = dep[11];
        dep[11] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 120 && x < 130) {
        var deps = dep[12];
        dep[12] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 130 && x < 140) {
        var deps = dep[13];
        dep[13] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 140 && x < 150) {
        var dep2 = dep[14];
        dep[14] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 150 && x < 160) {
        var deps = dep[15];
        dep[15] = deps + 1;


    } else if (x >= 160 && x < 170) {
        var deps = dep[16];
        dep[16] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 170 && x < 180) {
        var deps = dep[17];
        dep[17] = deps + 1;

    } else if (x >= 180 && x < 190) {
        var deps = dep[18];
        dep[18] = dep2 + 1;

    } else if (x >= 190 && x < 200) {
        var deps = dep[19];
        dep[19] = dep2 + 1;

    } else {
        var dep2 = dep[10];
        dep[20] = dep2 + 1;

    }

}
```

My question is, is there a cleaner way to do this or would I need to write an else if statement for each possible variable?

Comment: one is remove all else, you can  do comparison in switch see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679292/shortening-a-javascript-if-else-structure)

Comment: Yeah... There's a pattern, that's for sure. Round x to lowest 10.

Answer (score 3):

Besides your else statement, there is a clear pattern here. So the easiest thing to do is have an exception for that and then treat the rest together.

```
function depth(x) {
    var dep = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    if (x >= 200) { // case for anything above 200
       return dep[20] = dep[10] + 1;
    }
    dep[Math.floor(x/10)]++;
}
```

Your else case made it a little messier, but in general, this is a 1 liner kind of thing.

Comment: This seems to have solved it perfectly, http://i.imgur.com/4REemZM.jpg thank you for your help

Comment: Great stuff! Hope it helped.

Comment: Why not using `Math.max()` instead of the `if` statement?

Comment: @Jivan it's not incrementing del[20] if it's over 200, it's adding one to dep[10] and assigning that to dep[20]. That's why yours is still wrong.. I think it's messy, but considering the dep[10] in there, it's hard to see how it could be made much better.

Comment: @Niall ok got it, thanks - I don't really see another (cleaner) way in that case.

Comment: @Jivan yeah agreed, it's almost a pity, because it makes it a lot more awkward

Comment: Yeah. I hesitate between "this was a typo" and "Nixsy wanted to see if there's a way to automate a pattern when there is a behavioral exception such as this one"

Answer (score 2):

### A problem of repeating patterns

The problem is that you repeat yourself a lot because the code in your `if/else` statements share lots of similarities.

When you find such similarities in places of your code, it is often useful to "merge" them in some way.

For example, you could note that the code in your statements is perfectly identical except the `10, 20, 30` etc values. Then, try to determine a way to make those `10, 20, 30, 40`, depend on an unique variable with which you'll replace them.

In that case, it's easy to guess because each time, the array's key that you're working with is equal your number divided by 10. With the help of some methods of the JavaScript's built-in object `Math`, this is a matter of some single-line statements:

```
function depth(x) {
    var dep = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    var nb = Math.floor(x / 10);
    nb = Math.max(nb, 20);
    dep[nb]++;
}
```

### Some resources about Math functions:

[Math.max on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

[Math.floor on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

[JavaScript Math built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: Yeah, it's easy enough to see a pattern and than simplify it into this short statement, that's one of the most important tasks of a programmer :-)

Comment: you can simplify it event more - instead of the last 2 lines you can type `dep[nb]++`

Comment: Haha great, I was just doing that while you were typing

Comment: Just documenting here, as I mentioned below, that `Math.max` doesn't solve this. The aim isn't to increment dep[20] if it's over 200, it's adding one to dep[10] and assigning that to dep[20]. Very different.

Comment: You're perfectly right Niall. But I'll let my answer as is, because I can't find any way better than yours to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var index = Math.floor(x/10);
var deps = dep[index];
dep[index] = deps + 1;
```

Comment: This only works if x is a multiple of 10. Look at the other answers to see the correct way to get from x to an index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick but since your dep is local and never returned the function will do nothing.

```
function depth(x) {
    var dep = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    if(x < 200) {
      var index = Math.floor(x/10);
      dep[index]++;
    } else {
      dep[20] = dep[10] + 1;
    }
}
```

Anyway, as you probably guessed, when you see a pattern you can probably reduced it to something simpler.

If you have ranges of `10`, it means you can divide the numbers by `10` to get an index. You have to use `Math.floor` because `1/2 => 0.5` and It will try to add the value to the index "0.5" which doesn't exists. `Math.floor` will truncate the number to the lowest value. In our case, `0,1,2,3,4...`.

There is no global rule, but when you see a pattern that repeat itself, you just have to find what is common between each case and you'll be able to find ways to simplify most situations by converting values to something that will be common to all `ifs`.

Comment: I added dep to the function to display what I was incrementing, The dep array is global on the script.

Comment: @there I added the last condition