# cannot convert from boolean to int

Tags: java, int, boolean

I am trying to create a program that prompts the user to enter in the weight of the package and display the cost. I am new to the switch statement, which is why I feel it may have something to do with those statements. However, I return the error "cannot convert from boolean to int". I have looked at other situations where this comes up, but have not found a solution. Using == did not change it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise03_18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the package: ");
        int weight = input.nextInt();

        switch (weight) {
        case weight <= 1:
            System.out.println("The cost is 3.5");
        break;
        case weight <= 3:
            System.out.println("The cost is 5.5");
        break;
        case weight <= 10:
            System.out.println("The cost is 8.5");
        break;
        case weight <= 20:
            System.out.println("The cost is 10.5");
        default: System.out.println("The package cannot be shipped");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: the switch(weight) is switching on an int, but the case expression "weight<=1" is a Boolean. This boolean cannot be converted to an int. hence the odd message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not valid Java:

```
case weight <= 1:
```

You need to rephrase the `switch` as a series of `if` statements.

```
if (weight <= 1) {
    System.out.println("The cost is 3.5");
} else if (weight <= 3) {
    System.out.println("The cost is 5.5");
} ...
```

Comment: So when would case statements be used then? i thought that switch statements got rid of the need to do multiple if statements

Comment: @sjelmo5: It is useful when you are selecting *between fixed values*. In your case, you are dealing with *ranges*, which makes the `switch` statement unsuitable.

Answer (score 2):

This post is relevant
[Switch statement for greater-than/less-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than)

When you use switch you can only put equations in `cases`

```
switch(x)
{
case 1:
//...
break;

case 2:
//...
break;

}
```