# Why does my switch statement parameter require a boolean?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, boolean

From my understanding, inside a switch statement parameter is supposed to be the item you are comparing against all your cases and returns the correct case.

My question is why does my switch statement require I put in the boolean true and not the "score" argument to which I am comparing all my cases? Thanks!

Heres the exercise

```
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {
  switch (true) {
    case (score > 100 || score < 0):
      return 'INVALID SCORE';
      break;
    case (score <=100 && score >= 90):
      return 'A';
      break;
    case (score <=89 && score >= 80):
      return 'B';
      break;
    case (score <=79 && score >= 70):
      return 'C';
      break;
    case (score <=69 && score >= 60):
      return 'D';
      break;
    case (score <=59 && score >= 0):
      return 'F';
      break;
  }
  return score;
}
```

Comment: Because those cases return boolean values. When you pass the score everything inside `()`, next to `case` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JS evaluates an expression in the parenthesis before it compares with the switch argument. Consider this example:

`convertScoreToGrade(71);`

```
function convertScoreToGrade(score) {
  switch (true) {
    case (false):
      return 'INVALID SCORE';
      break;
    case (false):
      return 'A';
      break;
    case (false):
      return 'B';
      break;
    case (true):
      return 'C';
      break;
    case (false):
      return 'D';
      break;
    case (false):
      return 'F';
      break;
  }
  return score;
}
```

Great explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/5191552).