# How to get and set values in different tabs of a google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with **TAB A** and **TAB B**.

I want to loop through **TAB A** and get a matrix of values which I want to paste in **TAB B**.

It is throwing Errors, "Cannot read property 1, etc

```js
function getValuesFromModal(form) {
  var IdeasCounter = 0;
  const IDEA = 10,
    PROD = 26,
    PROM = 20,
    CLIENT = 4,
    ORANGE = "#e69138",
    GREEN = "#6aa84f",
    RED = "#e06666";
  var rangeSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records").getRange("A2:V").getValues();
  var rangeDest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Board").getRange("A2:E");


  for (i in rangeSource) {
    if (rangeSource[i][0] == "Ideas" && (!isNaN(parseInt(rangeSource[i][17])))) {
      rangeDest[IdeasCounter][0].setValue("( " + rangeSource[i][2] + " )" + "\n" + rangeSource[i][3] + "\n\n" + "[ " + rangeSource[i][17] + " ]");
      switch (rangeSource[i][17]) {
        case rangeSource[i][17] < (IDEA - 2):
          rangeDest[IdeasCounter][0].setBackground(GREEN);
          break;
        case rangeSource[i][17] > (IDEA):
          rangeDest[IdeasCounter][0].setBackground(RED);
          break;
        case rangeSource[i][17] < (IDEA):
          rangeDest[IdeasCounter][0].setBackground(ORANGE);
          break;
      }
      IdeasCounter++;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you already looked at [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)? If so, could you share the code you've attempted with?

Comment: I have just added the snippet. Thanks

Comment: "for (i in rangeSource) {"  and then using i as index seems shady - are you sure that i is integer values 0..length instead of some values from the rangeSource? Add a console.log(i) right after the for... line to check.

Comment: I have edited the code to make it look simpler, please someone try and let me know what's wrong. Why am I not able to set values through loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few issues with your script, and have modified it accordingly:

- I renamed `rangeSource` as you were pulling the values, not the actual range.
- I then created new arrays for the destination values and the cell backgrounds. This is necessary so that, on running the script, previously existing values and background colors will not be overwritten. Also, iterating through an array of a range's values is *[much faster](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)* than iterating through the range.
- You were using a `for..in` loop, but you shouldn't do that here. Instead, use a sequential for loop. Please take a look at [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1329498) to understand why. (Also, you can't loop through a Google `Range` class using the Array `[][]` notation. You would have to use the very slow [`getCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow-column) method on the range, but it is *vveeerrryyy ssssllooowwww*.)
- I saved `sourceValues[i][17]` to its own variable, but you should, ideally, do so for the other `sourceValues[i][*]` values as it will be easier to read and maintain.
- The `switch` statement is incorrect as it is not really meant to handle `<`/`>` comparisons. Again, someone else's explanation on both how you could do it, and why you should not do it is better than mine; you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/1329498).
- I then used [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) as they're much faster, to [write the destination value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))s and [set the cell background colors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor).

After modification, this is what resulted:

```
function getValuesFromModal(form) {
  var IdeasCounter = 0;
  const IDEA = 10,
    PROD = 26,
    PROM = 20,
    CLIENT = 4,
    ORANGE = "#e69138",
    GREEN = "#6aa84f",
    RED = "#e06666";
  var sourceValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records").getRange("A2:V").getValues();
  var destRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Board").getRange("A2:A"); // Looked like you were only writing to column A
  var destNewValues = destRange.getValues();
  var destBackgrounds = destRange.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<sourceValues.length; i++) {
    var ideaValue = sourceValues[i][17];
    if (sourceValues[i][0] == "Ideas" && (!isNaN(parseInt(ideaValue)))) {
      var destValue = "( " + sourceValues[i][2] + " )\n" + sourceValues[i][3] + "\n\n[ " + ideaValue + " ]";
      destNewValues[i][0] = destValue;
      if (ideaValue < (IDEA - 2)) { // Right now excluding ideaValue == 10
        destBackgrounds[i] = [GREEN];
      } else if (ideaValue > IDEA) {
        destBackgrounds[i] = [RED];
      } else if (ideaValue < IDEA) {
        destBackgrounds[i] = [ORANGE];
      }
    }
  }
  destRange.setValues(destNewValues).setBackgrounds(destBackgrounds);
}
```

Comment: Great work! You saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot!