# Returning a value from switch statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, switch-statement, return

I'm new to web development (JS) and I know there are many topics matching the title of mine, but no similar questions were answered, or maybe because I'm newbie, couldn't find.

In the code below I wanted my function and switch statements, to retrieve values from the arrays (bills) and in order to calculate new value, which to be assigned into a new non-existing place into the array `tips`. As a final result I want the function to return `tips` array with the value, depending on the case.

I know another way for solving this, anyway I was wondering whats wrong here, because that idea for `solving` it first came to my mind, and I thought it would work.

Here is my code:

```
var tips = [];
var bills = [124, 48, 264];

function tipCalc(bills, tips){
 switch(bills){
    case bills < 50:
      tips[0] = bills[1] * 0.2;
      break;

    case bills > 50:
      tips[1] = bills[0] * 0.5;
      break;

    default:
      console.log('no tips left.');
  }
  return tips;
}

tips = tipCalc(bills[0]);
console.log(tips);

enter code here
```

Comment: Use `Array.push` to add a new entry to an array in JavaScript, and use the `return` keyword to return a value or object.

Comment: This is not how [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works. `bills` is a number, `bills < 50` and `bills > 50` are booleans. They will never match. `tips` is undefined, since you never pass an argument for this parameter.

Comment: What is `bills < 50`? And you use switch check `bills = (bills < 50)`

Comment: var tips = [];
var bills = [124, 48, 264];

function tipCalc(bills){
 switch(true){
    case bills < 50:
      tips[0] = bills[1] * 0.2;
      break;

    case bills >= 50 && bills <= 200:
      tips[1] = bills[0] * 0.15;
      break;

    case bills > 200:
      tips[2] = bills[2] * 0.1;

    default:
      console.log('no tips left.');
  }

  return tips;
}

console.log(tipCalc(bills[1]));

Comment: well thats my code for the moment, i dont know how to paste it again formatted btw.. so excuse me.. i understood that for the switch statement and matching types between switch and case.

Comment: But `bills < 50` ?  `bills` is Array, 50 is Number

Comment: it does not matter, because it evaulate as true or false(boolean). And so.. it matches/or not with the switch.

Comment: No, It is alway false, because you campare Array and Number

Comment: Um, yeah its an array, but im passing it as an argument. I just pass one number from the array. My arguments is bills - so if i pass bills[0], ill pass the first number from the array. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this code down a bit and talk about what it's doing

```
var tips = [];
var bills = [124, 48, 264];
```

This part is declaring two variables in the global scope, which will both be accessible by any functions for both reading and writing (important - Google JS closures).

```
function tipCalc(bills, tips){
 switch(bills){
```

You have now started a function which calls a switch to evaluate the value of bills. Because you are passing in `bills[0]`, it will be evaluating bills[0] (124). It also accepts a second parameter called tips, which is undefined because no second argument is passed in when the function is called.

```
case bills < 50:
  tips[0] = bills[1] * 0.2;
  break;
```

This part is broken. If it was changed to an `if` statement, it would evaluate to false.

```
case bills > 50:
  tips[1] = bills[0] * 0.5;
  break;
```

Also broken. If changed to `if` statement, it would evaluate to true and be executed, but it would be performing an operation on undefined. If you didn't h have a second param also named `tips`, then you would be setting the global `tips` to 62.

```
    default:
      console.log('no tips left.');
  }
```

This is the part that should currently be executed because it is the only one that can be true with the other two cases being structured incorrectly.

```
  return tips;
}
```

Will return undefined because tips (within the scope of the function itself) began as undefined and has not been altered.

```
  tips = tipCalc(bills[0]);
  console.log(tips);
  enter code here
```

Breaks the whole program, should be a comment with `//` at the beginning.

Comment: fantastically well replied to :)

Comment: i'd probably add an explanation to one part as i do here in ()'s : "Because you are passing in bills[0] (at the bottom of the example),"

Answer (score 0):

well, this is not good approach, but if it is required for you to use Switch you can try like this without bills array at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tips = [];



    function tipCalc(bill) {
        switch (true) {
            case (bill < 50):
                tips.push(bill * 0.2);
                break;

            case (bill > 50):

                tips.push(bill * 0.5);
                break;

            default:
                console.log('no tips left.');
        }
        return tips;
    }

    tipCalc(10);
    for (let index = 0; index < tips.length; index++) {
        console.log(tips[index]);

    }



</script>
```

Or in case you need to compare bills array and depends to the value insert to tips array i would make it like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tips = [];
    var bills = [124, 48, 264];

    function tipCalc(bills) {
     for (let index = 0; index < bills.length; index++) {

         if (bills[index] <=50) {
            tips.push(bills[index] * 0.2);
         }
         else if (bills[index] >= 50) {
            tips.push(bills[index] * 0.5);
         }
         else 
             console.log("no tips left.");  
     }
    }

    tipCalc(bills);
    for (let index = 0; index < tips.length; index++) {
        console.log(tips[index]);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: The `else` clause can never be reached. Either it's `<=50` or `>=50`, there are no other possibilities.

Comment: Barmar => damm miss it :) thank you for bug discovery and i already fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verbose way of doing what I think you want to do. (add up the tips total)

```js
// create a blank tips array which we'll add to later
var tips = [];
// our bills array
var bills = [124, 48, 264];
// create a function that will calculate tips based on the bill totals
function calculateTips() {
  // create a counter that we will use to determine when we've reached the end of the loop
  var forEachCounter = 0;
  // for each will loop through each item in the bills array
  bills.forEach(function(amount) {
    //this increases the counter by 1 on each loop
    forEachCounter++;
    switch(true) {
      case (amount <= 50):
        // .push appends to the array
        tips.push(amount * 0.2);
        break;
      case (amount > 50):
        // amount is the value of the bill for this iteration * 0.5
        tips.push(amount * 0.5);
        break;
    }
    // if end of array has been reached
    // bills.length = the total amount of array items in bills arrat
    if (forEachCounter === bills.length) {
      // create a totalTips variable to add to
      var totalTips = 0;
      // create another counter to detect when end is reached
      var forEachCounter2 = 0;
      // loop through the tips array
      tips.forEach(function(tipamount) {
        // add 1 to counter on each loop
        forEachCounter2++;
        // add to totalTips
        // can also do totalTips = totalTips + tipamount;
        totalTips += tipamount;
        // when end of tip array is reached..
        if (forEachCounter2 === tips.length) {
          //alert(totalTips);
          // output it to where you need it
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = totalTips;
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
// call it when you need it
calculateTips();
```

**note**

If you're working with a lot of tips (like an entire national restaurant chain) you may want to consider using if/else instead of switch because [switch is demonstrated to be slower with ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/3377049)

**fiddle with it here**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/p1kfgreq/

Comment: thank u for the good alternative, but yet my exercise was to do the following, just with if-else/switch, function, and some arrays. Some of the lines from ur code im still not familiar with, anyway thank u. Ill look up to it.

Comment: @ВенелинБорисов I added annotations to the code to help you understand it. Good luck!