# How can I turn this else if statement into a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I created a function to check the current URL of a website each second & change the meta tag images in the `<head>` HTML element according to a certain value string. My code was perfectly, however I want to make my code more readable 7 optimized... so I want to turn this code into switch statement instead, but I am not able to figure it out by myself at this point.

Here is the code:

```
// Variable declarations
var imgOgSrc = $('meta[property="og:image"]');
var twitterImgSrc = $('meta[name="twitter:image:src"]');
var currentUrl;

// Checks for current url & changes meta tags depending on slug value
function getCurrentUrl(){
    currentUrl = window.location.href;
    
    if(currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf('python') >= 0) {
            imgOgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
            twitterImgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
    }   else if (currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf('java') >= 0) {
            imgOgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
            twitterImgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
    }   else if (currentUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf('php') >= 0) {
            imgOgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
            twitterImgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
    }
        else {
            imgOgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
            twitterImgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the difference in the then parts?

Comment: For your use case, if statements would be the way to go. Checkout this answer that did speed tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/3684265

Comment: makes no sense to use switch when you are not looking for exact matches.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand Nina . Can you elaborate a bit more? @imvain2 thanks! I will take a look at this.

Comment: @epascarello I see, so you suggest that I leave my code the way it is?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, Nina is saying that the URLs are all the same in your attr contents for the if statements. So if that wasn't a typo, you only need one if and an else.

Comment: I would match the url differently and I would combine the ifs since it is the same content in each.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't explain myself properly. The image will also change depending of the string. Anyway, I got the answered that I was looking. Thanks to everybody! You guys rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var currentUrl;

function getCurrentUrl() {
  currentUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

  var langType = function(type) {
    return currentUrl.indexOf(type) > -1;
  }

  switch (true) {
    case langType('python'):
      imgOgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
      twitterImgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
      break;

    case langType('java'):
      // ...
      break;

    case langType('php'):
      // ...
      break;

    default:
      // ...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, it would work, but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Not the best, yeah, I would personally go with Taki's solution myself. Was just trying to stick with OP's choice of using `switch`.

Answer (score 3):

Since all the `if` conditions have the same code, you could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this.

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
  currentUrl = window.location.href;
  const customUrlNeeded = ['python', 'java', 'php'].some(a => currentUrl.toLowerCase().includes(a))

  if (customUrlNeeded) {
    imgOgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
    twitterImgSrc.attr('content', 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg');
  } else {
    imgOgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
    twitterImgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take an object for `python`, `java` and `php` with `imgOgSrc` and `twitterImgSrc` properties amd use a `null` property for not matching URL.

```js
function getTarget(url) {
    const targets = { 
        python: {
            imgOgSrc: 'data1',
            twitterImgSrc: 'data2'
        },
        java: {
            imgOgSrc: 'data3',
            twitterImgSrc: 'data4'
        },
        php: {
            imgOgSrc: 'data5',
            twitterImgSrc: 'data6'
        },
        null: {                    // default values
            imgOgSrc: 'data7',
            twitterImgSrc: 'data8'
        }
    };
    return targets[url.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(Object.keys(targets).join('|')))];
}

console.log(getTarget('blablajavabla'));
console.log(getTarget('blablabla'));
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `switch/case`, you can store the images in an object, see if the `currentUrl` has the keyword, extract it then use it to get the values from that object :

```
// Variable declarations
var imgOgSrc = $('meta[property="og:image"]');
var twitterImgSrc = $('meta[name="twitter:image:src"]');
var currentUrl;

function getCurrentUrl(){
  currentUrl = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

  const obj = {
    python : {
      imgOgSrc : 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg',
      twitterImgSrc :  'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg'
    },
    java : {
      imgOgSrc : 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg',
      twitterImgSrc :  'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg'
    },
    php : {
      imgOgSrc : 'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg',
      twitterImgSrc :  'http://carrieres.nameofwebsite.com/static/img/custom-img.jpg'
    }
  }

  const word = currentUrl.match(/php | java | python /gi)[0];

  if(word){
    imgOgSrc.attr('content', obj[word].imgOgSrc);
    twitterImgSrc.attr('content', obj[word].twitterImgSrc);    
  }
  else {
    imgOgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
    twitterImgSrc.attr('content', currentUrl);
  }
}
```