# Function returning undefined value, a bit confused

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to solve a problem for a course I'm currently doing, but I've been stuck on why my code returns undefined for about an hour now.

I've switched a few things around, added brackets to make sure things are in order, idk what else to try.

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268];

function tipsCalculator(bill) {
  switch (bill) {
    case bill < 50:
      return (bill * (20 / 100));

    case bill >= 50 && bill <= 200:
      return (bill * (15 / 100));

    case bill > 200:
      return (bill * (10 / 100));
  }
}

var testing = tipsCalculator(bills[0]);
console.log(testing);
```

I expect it to return the calculation of the `124 * whichever` case that value fits.

Comment: you have to use if(..) {...} else if(..) {...} else {...} because switch-case uses constants in predicate

Comment: You can't use comparison on [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) like `case bill > 200`. Use `if-else-if` instead.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 6):

That's not a valid use of [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). You will have to use `if` statements:

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268];

function tipsCalculator(bill) {
  if (bill < 50)
    return (bill * (20 / 100));

  if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200)
    return (bill * (15 / 100));

  if (bill > 200)
    return (bill * (10 / 100));
}

var testing = tipsCalculator(bills[0]);
console.log(testing);
```

The reason it doesn't work is because expressions like `bill < 50` evaluate to a boolean value -- either `true` or `false`. So when your code executes `tipsCalculator(bills[0])` the function looks like this:

```
function tipsCalculator(124) { // bills[0] == 124
  switch (124) {
    case false: // 124 > 50 == false
      return (124 * (20 / 100));

    case true: // 124 >= 50 == true, 124 <= 200 == true, thus true && true == true
      return (124 * (15 / 100));

    case false: // 124 > 200 == false
      return (124 * (10 / 100));
  }
}
```

As you can see, the only cases are `true` and `false`, but `124` is neither of those, so your function completes without entering any of the cases and since no return statements are executed, the return value is `undefined`.

Comment: So in which case would I use a switch statement? Thank you by the way, I was trying to avoid using if else statements because I knew how to do those.

Comment: Basically it's for situations where you need to take a certain action based on a single value -- for example, you could do `case 50:` and it would execute the following code if `bill` was exactly 50. Take a look at the linked documentation for more examples of how it works.

Comment: Expression's can be used with switch, although I still prefer if-else

Comment: @Satpal Not in exactly the sense one would expect though, and I'm not sure it's a great pattern.

Comment: @RojayArinze I updated the answer with some more details about why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You use switch in wrong way, you can use it as follows

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268];

function tipsCalculator(bill) {
  let b = bill < 50 ? 1 : (bill <= 200 ? 2 : 3)
  switch (b) {
    case 1:
      return (bill * (20 / 100));
    case 2:
      return (bill * (15 / 100));
    case 3:
      return (bill * (10 / 100));
  }
}

var testing = tipsCalculator(bills[0]);
console.log(testing);
```

Comment: That might work for this situation, but in general that makes the code kind of confusing to maintain if you need to change the cases later.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `true` in `switch` case.

```js
var bills = [124, 48, 268];

function tipsCalculator(bill) {
  switch (true) {
    case (bill < 50):
      return (bill * (20 / 100));

    case (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200):
      return (bill * (15 / 100));

    case (bill > 200):
      return (bill * (10 / 100));

  }
}

var testing = tipsCalculator(bills[0]);
console.log(testing);
```

Comment: Note that this method has [very poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/574531).

Comment: ya I know, but he mentioned in your comment section, that he only want to use switch.

Comment: Why does true allow it to work? Is it because the value being evaluated has to remain constant in the switch?

Comment: the `case` will check only what you pass in `switch`. if you pass true and if the case matches it will also return true. so, the case will allow it to get in that block