# why does this simple switch statement always run the default

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Ok guys, It seems like this switch statement is forever doomed to NOT work.

The initial idea was to create a variable x which is a prompt, the user will have to select enter any number and that would be the value of x.

Then under the first case of the switch, if x is less than 0.5 then it will simply console.log "less". 
If x is more than 0.5 it will simply console.log "more". 
If for some reason the program didn't work as expected the default is to console.log "this is the default"

Then i added a console.log of x in the end just to know what  number did the user enter.

Lets try it!

I tried and tried and regardless of what number i enter it always printed "this is the default". Then printed the value of x.

I ended up going Rambo and removing the prompt and declaring x to be 0.6. It ought to print "more" but it still doesn't.

```js
var x = 0.6;

switch (x) {
  case x < 0.5:
    console.log("less");
    break;
  case x > 0.5:
    console.log("more");
    break;

  default:
    console.log("its the dflt");
};

console.log(x);
```

So I'm wondering whats wrong with this code. Help

Comment: Thanks certainperformance, i was sure someone was bewitching my code lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`switch` compares what you `switch` with against the `case`s. So, if you have `case x < 0.5:` which you want to run, that case will run if the expression you `switched` against was `true`:

```js
var x = 0.6;

switch (true) {
  case x < 0.5:
    console.log("less");
    break;
  case x > 0.5:
    console.log("more");
    break;

  default:
    console.log("its the dflt");
};

console.log(x);
```

If you `switch` against `x` itself, a `case` will only run if the case evaluates to the same value as `x`, which, here, is `0.6`, eg:

```js
var x = 0.6;

switch (x) {
  case 0.6:
    console.log('x is exactly 0.6');
    break;
  default:
    console.log("x is something other than 0.6");
};

console.log(x);
```

But that's not flexible at all, and isn't what you want.

Personally, I'd prefer `if`/`else`, it's a lot easier to read (and, as some points out in comments, is a lot faster):

```js
var x = 0.6;
if (x < 0.5) {
    console.log("less");
} else if (x > 0.5) {
    console.log("more");
} else {
    console.log('neither less nor more; equal or NaN');
}
```

Comment: Or `switch (x>5)`, `case true/false` and `default`, although using a `switch` for OP's use case is rather redundant anyway.

Comment: Please do not use `switch(true)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/36866

Answer (score 0):

Switch compares the value of `x` to the **value** of the cases. In your code `x < 0.5` evaluates to `true`. Instead of going to that case like if-statements, the switch case compares `x` and `true`. Since `x` is a number, `x` will never equal `true` so the default case is always taken.

I would use if-statements instead of a switch in this instance. Switches are better for enumerations (checking if `x` is a specific value out of a set of values, not a range of values)

Answer (score 0):

CertainPerformance has answered you question very well however if you still don't understand how to use switch I would recommend you use "if statements" until you have the time to read more on using switch.

```js
var x = 0.6;

if (x < 0.5) {
  console.log("less");
}
else if (x > 0.5) {
  console.log("more");
}
else {
  console.log("its the dflt");
}

console.log(x);
```

Hope this is easier for you :)