# Call a getter of different javascript file using string

Tags: javascript

In my automation code,I have two javascript file having different class and some getters.
I get some input from user and depending on that input, i create the name of getter during runtime and access the getter of both classes.

I am able to access the getter of same class but i am facing issue while accessing the getter of different class.

```
const AutomationClass2 = require('./AutomationClass2.js')
class AutomationClass1 extends Page {
  get GeneralTile() {
    return browser.isAndroid ? $(~abc) :$(~abc)
  }

  navigateLandingPage(page, tab) { 
    if (tab == "tab") {
       //page=zones, tab=tab
      var lObj = page+ "Tab"          //facing issue while accessing the getter of "AutomationClass2"
      AutomationClass2.lObj.waitForExist(20000)     //facing issue
      AutomationClass2.lObj.click()                 //facing issue
    }
    else if (tab == "zone") {
      //page=General
      var lObj = page+ "Tile"         //GeneralTile
      this[lObj].waitForExist(20000)  //working fine
      this[lObj].click()              //working fine
    }
  }
}
```

AutomationClass2 looks like

```
class SettingGeneral extends Page {
  /**
   * define elements
   */


  get zonesTab() {
    console.log("in zones tab getter ")
    const elem = browser.isAndroid ? $('~TabZones') : $('~TabZones')
    return elem
  }
  }
```

In first if i.e "if (tab == "tab") {"
I am not able to access the getter "zonesTab" of class "AutomationClass2"
Thanks in Advance,It will be great help

Comment: You need to put it in square brackets on the second class too: Instead of `AutomationClass2.lObj.waitForExist(20000)` change it to `AutomationClass2[lObj].waitForExist(20000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (tab == "tab") {
       //page=zones, tab=tab
      var lObj = page+ "Tab"          //facing issue while accessing the getter of        "AutomationClass2"
      AutomationClass2[lObj].waitForExist(20000)     //facing issue
      AutomationClass2[lObj].click()                 //facing issue
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties in Javascript using square brackets. For instance using

```
AutomationClass2[lObj]
```

allows dynamic access to the propery.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access a property of an object, either by name or by variable:

```
AutomationClass2.lObj.waitForExist(20000); // trying to access a property named "lObj"
AutomationClass2[lObj].waitForExist(20000); // tyring to accses a property named by the lObj variable.
```

Comment: Enough rep to close as dup?

Comment: @mplungjan You already closed it as dup.

Comment: Yes, after you answered...

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, you mean that I should have closed it as dup instead of answering?

Comment: Yes :)..............

Comment: @mplungjan Well, I need to answer 11 more questions to get the gold badge in javascript....  I can't spend [this much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than/12259830#12259830) on every answer.

Comment: So this answer here is in fact rep hunting? ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Well, not rep, but number of answers ;)

Comment: @mplungjan Finally I have the gold badge for javascript :)