# When to use 'true' as the switch expression instead of a variable name?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am writing a switch statement in JavaScript and instead of giving an exact value as case value I use a comparison.

```
 switch (age) {
case age<18:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
case age>18:
    alert("You are an adult");
    }
```

This code did not give any output and then I changed the expression within switch into true.

```
 switch (true) {
case age<18:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
case age>18:
    alert("You are an adult");
    }
```

Could anybody please explain the reason why this code didn't work at the first attempt.

Comment: I've never seem `switch(true)`, but I think it's a interesting way for pattern matching :)

Comment: @appleapple You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/1823841) for some more interesting way for pattern matching :)

Comment: @palaѕн thanks for the link, but the answer you linked, while looks like have many choice, most of them are hash/lookup (and are in fact not-that-related to switch). When I say pattern matching, I'm more interested in generalized switch like `switch(true){case foo instanceof Foo:dosomething();}` thanks for inform me anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` uses `===` to compare the switched expression against every case. For example, if `age` is 13, then

```
switch (age) {
  case age < 18:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
  case age > 18:
    alert("You are an adult");
}
```

evaluates to

```
switch (13) {
  case 13 < 18:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
  case 13 > 18:
    alert("You are an adult");
}
```

which is

```
switch (13) {
  case true:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
  case false:
    alert("You are an adult");
}
```

The switched expression, `13`, is not equal to any of the `case`s.

You need to logic your way through it - if, when using `switch`, your switched expression is not going to be `===` to any of the cases, use `switch(true)`, which works if the cases are conditionally true:

```
switch (true) {
  case age < 18:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
  case age > 18:
    alert("You are an adult");
}
```

when `age` is `13`, evaluates to

```
switch (true) {
  case true:
    alert("You are a child");
    break;
  case false:
    alert("You are an adult");
}
```

Now, the switched expression `true` is `===` to one of the cases.

*Or*, even better, just use `if`/`else`, there are rarely any good times to use `switch` IMO:

```
if (age < 18) {
  console.log('You are a child');
} else {
  console.log('You are an adult');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple, clear explanation. Now I see the point.

Answer (score 1):

What the Switch does is compare for equality between the value and the cases. So, in this case, it is comparing the age value (for example 10) to the value true of `age < 18`. So this would trigger the alert in the second example. But `18 !== true`, and `18 !== false` too, so this wouldn't trigger any alert.