# conditional statement if value is greater or less then show error

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, weather-api

I am trying to display a warning message if the temperature is higher then 40 or above - 10
but is not working.

I read some websites and in StackOverflow I found this [Switch statement for greater-than/less-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than) to try to solve the problem but I still couldn't find a solution for what might be happening.

Can you help me out?

Many thanks.

```js
function Celsius(kelvin) {
    let celsiusTemp = Math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
    if (celsiusTemp > 35) {
        console.log('too hot, use sunscreen ')
    } else
    if (celsiusTemp < 5) {
        console.log('too cold, get warm ')
    } else {
        return celsiusTemp + `°C`;
    }
};
```

Comment: so what is a sample call that does not work/?

Comment: doesn't show anything in the console

Comment: the code looks OK to me. Could use final ";" on console logs, and of course you'd have to invoke the function to see if it is working. But there's nothing wrong I can see.

Comment: It definitly works: https://jsbin.com/duhuwujoze/edit?js,console

Comment: again "so what is a sample call that does not work? "

Comment: it was supposed to show a warning if the temperature is above value°C or below -value°C. I don't really understand whats happening that is affecting it to work.  I see your link and is surprisingly working. it might be my text editor.

Comment: I Guess you are not showing us the calls that did not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
Celsius(kelvin) {
    let celsiusTemp = Math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
    if (celsiusTemp < 35 || celsiusTemp > 5) {
      return celsiusTemp + `°C`;
    }
    if (celsiusTemp > 35) {
      return celsiusTemp + `°C, too hot, use sunscreen`;
    }
    if (celsiusTemp < 5) {
      return celsiusTemp + `°C,too cold, get warm`;
    }
}

//call method Celsius(298) here like this

console.log(this.Celsius(298));

//or 

console.log(Celsius(298));
```