# Switch/case using logic operators such as >= and &&

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, logical-operators

I have this code that first reads which position of a checkbox is checked and then executes several ifs. Then I thought I could make the code smaller if I used switch/case, while also portfolio-ing the command for later uses. The command was like this:

```
if (fsex[0].checked {
gender = 'man'
if (age >= 0 && age <= 10) {
img.setAttribute('src', 'male-baby.png')
} else if
```

I tried using switch by changing the below "gender" line to something like this:

```
switch (age) {
case (age >=0 && age <= 10):
img.setAttribute('src', 'male-baby.png')
break
case ...etc
```

This didn't work.

Then I tried with `case >=0`, which then the VSCode immediatly returns a sintax error "expression expected.

Is there a way I can use switch/case to this one? Or I should just stick with several if/ else ifs?

Comment: You should just stick with several if/else, that's correct.

Comment: also if you consider performance, please take a look at this detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/8389449

Comment: "portfolio-ing" a) please don't verb nouns; b) are you talking about templatizing? Or something else?

Comment: Just trying to use switch instead of if/else in this one so I could show the command. Nothing else. Niloy, thanks for the post, I can now see in every situation if/else is faster than switch. But I would know if you can use switch with these logical operators anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this "trick":

```js
const age = 14;

switch(true) 
{
  case age > 5 && age <= 10:
    console.log('bla 1');
  break;
  case age > 10 && age <= 20:
    console.log('bla 2');
  break;
  case age > 20 && age <= 30:
    console.log('bla 3');
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `case` branch of a `switch` statement expects an *expression*, and the value of the expression will be compared to the initial argument. In this case, that means you are comparing `age` to either `true` or `false` (the result of the expression `(age >= 0 && age <= 10)`. You can technically use `switch (true)` for this, but there isn't much value in doing so.

This said, there are other patterns that allow you to express what you are trying to do without a conditional with many branches. For example:

```js
[
  { max: 10, callback: () => { img.setAttribute("src", "example.jpg") }, 
  { max: 15, callback: () => { ... },
  { max: 20, callback: () => { ... },
].find(({ max }) => max >= age)?.callback()
```

Or if you really don't care about others understanding the code in the future you can take advantage of consistent insertion-retrieval order:

```js
const conditions = {
  10: () => { console.log("a") }, 
  15: () => { console.log("b") },
  Infinity: () => { console.log("c") },
}

Object.entries(conditions).find(([max]) => max >= age)?.[1]()
```

Comment: Using an object and arrow function into another object! A bit advanced for me but I'll try lol. Thanks