# Javascript one line If...else...else if statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I know you can set variables with one line if/else statements by doing `var variable = (condition) ? (true block) : (else block)`, but I was wondering if there was a way to put an else if statement in there. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks everyone!

Comment: Nested ternary operator is what you are describing. Looks like this answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526739/a-somewhat-painful-triple-nested-ternary-operator

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Sure, you can do nested ternary operators but they are hard to read.

```
var variable = (condition) ? (true block) : ((condition2) ? (true block2) : (else block2))
```

Comment: Yeah, in this case `if() { ... } else if() { ... } else { ... }` is probably more readable.

Comment: Any ternary operators are hard to read. They're terse and not descriptive. Even non programmers have an idea what if () else () might mean.

Comment: Hard to read... unless you use line breaks and indents properly, then it can be quite easy.

Answer (score 66):

## tl;dr

**Yes, you can...** *If a then a, else if b then if c then c(b), else b, else null*

```
a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b) : null)

a
  ? a
  : b
      ? c
        ? c(b)
        : b
      : null
```

## longer version

Ternary operator `?:` used as inline if-else is **right associative**. In short this means that the rightmost `?` gets fed first and it takes exactly **one** closest operand on the left and **two**, with a `:`, on the right.

Practically speaking, consider the following statement *(same as above)*:

## `a ? a : b ? c ? c(b) : b : null`

The rightmost `?` gets fed first, so find it and its surrounding *three arguments* and consecutively expand to the left to another `?`.

```
   a ? a : b ? c ? c(b) : b : null
                 ^                  <---- RTL
1.            |1-?-2----:-3|
             ^ <-
2.        |1-?|--2---------|:-3---|
     ^ <-
3.|1-?-2-:|--3--------------------|

result: a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b) : null)
```

### This is how computers read it:

> 1. Term `a` is read.
>    Node: **`a`**
> 2. Nonterminal `?` is read.
>    Node: **`a ?`**
> 3. Term `a` is read.
>    Node: **`a ? a`**
> 4. Nonterminal `:` is read.
>    Node: **`a ? a :`**
> 5. Term `b` is read.
>    Node: **`a ? a : b`**
> 6. Nonterminal `?` is read, triggering the right-associativity rule. Associativity decides:
>    node: **`a ? a : (b ?`**
> 7. Term `c` is read.
>    Node: **`a ? a : (b ? c`**
> 8. Nonterminal `?` is read, re-applying the right-associativity rule.
>    Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ?`**
> 9. Term `c(b)` is read.
>    Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b)`**
> 10. Nonterminal `:` is read.
>     Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) :`**
> 11. Term `b` is read.
>     Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b`**
> 12. Nonterminal `:` is read. The ternary operator `?:` from previous scope is satisfied and the scope is closed.
>     Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b) :`**
> 13. Term `null` is read.
>     Node: **`a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b) : null`**
> 14. No tokens to read. Close remaining open parenthesis.
>     #Result is: `a ? a : (b ? (c ? c(b) : b) : null)`

## Better readability

The ugly oneliner from above could *(and should)* be rewritten for readability as:
*(Note that the indentation does **not** implicitly define correct closures as brackets () do.)*

```
a
  ? a
  : b
      ? c
        ? c(b)
        : b
      : null
```

for example

```
return a + some_lengthy_variable_name > another_variable
        ? "yep"
        : "nop"
```

## More reading

[Mozilla: JavaScript Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
[Wiki: Operator Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

---

## Bonus: Logical operators

```
var a = 0 // 1
var b = 20
var c = null // x=> {console.log('b is', x); return true} // return true here!

a
  && a
  || b
      && c
        && c(b) // if this returns false, || b is processed
        || b
      || null
```

*Using logical operators as in this example is ugly and wrong, but this is where they shine...*

#### "Null coalescence"

<sub>*This approach comes with subtle limitations as explained in the link below. For proper solution, see Nullish coalescing in Bonus2.*</sub>

```
function f(mayBeNullOrFalsy) {
  var cantBeNull = mayBeNullOrFalsy || 42                    // "default" value
  var alsoCantBe = mayBeNullOrFalsy ? mayBeNullOrFalsy : 42  // ugly...
  ..
}
```

#### Short-circuit evaluation

```
false && (anything) // is short-circuit evaluated to false.
true || (anything)  // is short-circuit evaluated to true.
```

[Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)
[Null coalescence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/985454)
[Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

---

## Bonus2: new in JS

#### Proper "Nullish coalescing"

[developer.mozilla.org~Nullish_coalescing_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
function f(mayBeNullOrUndefined, another) {
  var cantBeNullOrUndefined = mayBeNullOrUndefined ?? 42
  another ??= 37 // nullish coalescing self-assignment
  another = another ?? 37 // same effect
  ..
}
```

#### Optional chaining

Stage 4 finished proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
// before
var street = user.address && user.address.street
// after
var street = user.address?.street

// combined with Nullish coalescing
// before
var street = user.address
  ? user.address.street
  : "N/A"

// after
var street = user.address?.street ?? "N/A"

// arrays
obj.someArray?.[index]

// functions
obj.someMethod?.(args)
```

Comment: you're detail is siiiiick!

Answer (score 17):

In simple words:

```
var x = (day == "yes") ? "Good Day!" : (day == "no") ? "Good Night!" : "";
```

Answer (score 5):

This is use mostly for assigning variable, and it uses binomial conditioning eg.

```
var time = Date().getHours(); // or something

var clockTime = time > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM' ;
```

There is no ElseIf, for the sake of development don't use chaining,  you can use `switch` which is much faster if you have multiple conditioning in .js

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but thought I'd put my two cents in. Ternary operators are able to be nested in the following fashion:

```
var variable = conditionA ? valueA : (conditionB ? valueB: (conditionC ? valueC : valueD));
```

Example:

```
var answer = value === 'foo' ? 1 :
    (value === 'bar' ? 2 : 
        (value === 'foobar' ? 3 : 0));
```

Answer (score 5):

if-else:

```
a = b ? (true block) : (false block)
```

if-else if-else:

```
a = b ? (true block) : b = c ? (true block) : (false block)
```

if:

```
a = b && (true block)
```

if-else-if(nested):

```
a = b ? (true block) : b = c && (true block)
```

- note think so much, just implement and see the results, where a, b and c is variable

Comment: simple is better

Answer (score 3):

You can chain as much conditions as you want. If you do:

```
var x = (false)?("1true"):((true)?"2true":"2false");
```

You will get `x="2true"`

So it could be expressed as:

```
var variable = (condition) ? (true block) : ((condition)?(true block):(false block))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  a === "a" ? do something
: a === "b" ? do something
: do something
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

if i use code like this

`const alpha = a ? a : b ? b : c`

it will get

> Extract this nested ternary operation into an independent statement.

from so i recommend to use this

`const alpha = a || b || c`

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

This has worked much better for my use case when I was writing automation for n8n :)

You could accomplish this by wrapping your switch statement in an IIFE.

```js
(()=>{
  switch (key) {
    case 'foo' : return 4;
    default : return 1;
  }
})();
```