# Javascript two-lined if/else statement. What is this called?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

There's a one-lined if/else statement (ternary operations), as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043135/javascript-one-line-if-else-else-if-statement).

What about the two-lined ones?

e.g.

```
if (true) console.log("True");
else console.log("False");
```

edit: The 'normal' / *standard* if/else statements I see look like this:

```
if (true) {
   console.log("True");
} else {
   console.log("False");
}
```

So the difference: No curly brackets.

Comment: It's just called `if` statement and `else` statement. Or `if...else` statement as a combined term.

Comment: You can also put `if`/`else` on a single line or a conditional operator expression on multiple lines, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @VLAZ, I've edited my question to provide some clarification; the two lined one is different from the 'standard' if / else statement I have learned and see all the time, as it has no curly brackets.

Comment: @daCoda it doesn't have curly brackets because you don't need them *in this case*. If you don't put brackets, then the next statement belongs to the corresponding block. If you put the brackets in, you are explicitly grouping the statements together. `if (bool) satement1;` will resolve as if you have `if (bool) { statement1; }` - the two are equivalent. The only difference is the coding style. However `if (bool) satement1; statement2;` will resolve as `if (bool) { statement1; } statement2;` hence why most styleguides prefer the brackets, since you can more easily modify the block.

Comment: @VLAZ, cheers, got what I needed, that it's just a coding style.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator, or ternary operator, is called just that - the ternary operator or conditional operator. It is *not* called a "single-lined if-else statement" because, well, there's no if-else in it. (It might be *similar* to the effect of an if-else as a single expression, but that doesn't make it one)

The code in your question is just a plain if-else statement, since it uses if-else - no matter how many lines it has.

Comment: OP is asking about the use of if-else *in comparison to* the conditional operator: *There's a one-lined if/else statement (ternary operations), as seen here.* so I figured it was worth clarifying that the conditional operator is *not* a "one-lined if-else statement". (Rather, anything with `if-else` *is* an if-else statement)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is just a standart if-else. The absence of brackets is possible because you have only 1 statment inside the conditions. This can be applied anywhere where you would use brackets to have multiple statments. For example:

```
while(true) console.log("looping")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just differences in coding style; see @VLAZ's answer.