# pass variable to quotation in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have a web app, backend using Django, frontend using HTML5.

I want to pass a variable from bootstrap table to the quotation in javascript.

```
<th class ='Format_issued' data-field="book.publisher" data-formatter="renderFormat">Material Format</th>

<script>
            function renderFormat(value) {
            return '<select style="width: 7em" name="Material_format" id="Material_format" >\n' +
                '                <option value="">--Select--</option>\n' +
                '               <option value="eText" {% if ' + value + ' == "eText"  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>eText</option>\n' +
                '                <option value="No Material" {% if value == "No Material"  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>No Material</option>\n' +
                '              
                '            </select>'
        }
</script>
```

'value' is the variable that I want to pass.
But I have tried several method:
1 . use ' + value + ':   `'               <option value="eText" {% if ' + value + ' == "eText"  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>eText</option>\n'`

2 . use value in my js quotation directly:  '                `<option value="No Material" {% if value == "No Material"  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>No Material</option>\n'`

all could not pass the value variable.

How could I  pass 'value'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

**Always use javascript template literal when handling some complex string output.**
In your case, it's possible to combine template literals with JS ternary operator like this :

```
function renderFormat(value) {
    return `<select style="width: 7em" name="Material_format" id="Material_format">
    <option value="" ${(value === 'empty') ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}>--Select--</option>
    <option value="eText" ${(value === 'eText') ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}>eText</option>
    <option value="No Material" ${(value === 'No Material') ? 'selected="selected"' : ""}>No Material</option>
</select>`;
```

}

*Test output :*

```
console.log(renderFormat("No Material"));
// console.log(renderFormat("eText"));
// console.log(renderFormat("empty"));

// Output
<select style="width: 7em" name="Material_format" id="Material_format">
  <option value="" >--Select--</option>
  <option value="eText" >eText</option>
  <option value="No Material" selected="selected">No Material</option>
</select>
```

**NB :** *Do not mix Js template literals and Django template tags. Just a advice.*

More about [javascript ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043135/javascript-one-line-if-else-else-if-statement), and [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)