# JavaScript do expression: if statement without else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, ecmascript-next

I have a question about the proposed [JavaScript do expression construct](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-do-expressions). There are many examples that show how it can be used to return a value from a conditional statement that has both `if` and `else`. Also valid for `if` with `else if` and `else`.

What about a conditional that has just an `if` clause but no `else if` or `else`? Is this valid usage of the `do` expression?

My use case is for conditionally displaying content in a **React** component. I would like to write JSX code like so, but I am not sure if it is valid:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {do {
        if (true) {
          <p>If statement is true</p>
        }
      }}
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also asked the question in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dherman/1c97dfb25179fa34a41b5fff040f9879).

Comment: `do` expression is a stage 1 **proposal**, not part of ES2016 (ES7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what Babel does:

Input:

```
<p>
  {do {
    if (true) {
      <a/>
    }
  }}
</p>
```

Output:

```
React.createElement(
  "p",
  null,
  true ? React.createElement("a", null) : void 0
);
```

This makes sense to me. The return value in the implied `else` would be `undefined`.

Comment: In React, you want the return value for `else` (in this case) to be null, not undefined. Better to explicitly return null as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68169867/560114)

Comment: Then open a ticket with Babel. I didn't write this code in my answer, I'm only showing what the compiler did.

Comment: I was talking about the original source code before Babel transpiles it. So `{do {
    if (true) {
      <a/>
    }
    null
  }}`

Comment: ...or it looks like in the current version of the spec you would have an explicit `else` block (`else { null }`); not sure if Babel supports that yet

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about `do`, also as mentioned by @[Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

> do expression is a stage 1 proposal, not part of ES2016 (ES7).

---

You can write it like this using **[ternary operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)**, and `return null` if condition fails:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                true?
                    <p>If statement is true</p>
                :null
            }
            <p>I am always rendered</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or Use **[&& Operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)**:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                true && <p>If statement is true</p>
            }
            <p>I am always rendered</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Check the DOC for more details about **[Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)**.

Comment: `&&` operator is exactly what I was looking for. It makes the code cleaner and more succinct.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply do this ? Using the Ternary operator

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      { true ? <p>If statement is true</p> : null }
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a valid syntax to write a *do expression* without an else and it will return an `undefined` (`void 0`).

```js
let a = do {
  if (false) true
}

// a === undefined
```

We can also return a value at the end without even using `else` like this:

```js
let a = do {
  if (false) true
  null
}

// a === null
```

Especially for *ReactJS*, we have to return a `null` even using the *do expression*, because if it doesn't return something, the return value will be `undefined` which of course will error break the component rendering:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {do {
        if ([condition]) {
          <p>If statement is true</p>
        }
        null
      }}
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or, use the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which will also catch `undefined`:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {do {
        if ([condition]) {
          <p>If statement is true</p>
        }
      } ?? null}
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Other answers here suggest why bother using *do expression* since we can do this using the [Conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and the answer is that using the *ternary operator* when we'll have more than one condition won't be syntactical friendly and it will lead in miss-renders and [hard time understanding the logic for developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526739/a-somewhat-painful-triple-nested-ternary-operator):

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {[condition1]
        ? <p>If condition1 is true</p> :
       [condition2]
        ? <p>If condition2 is true</p> :
       [condition2]
        ? <p>If condition3 is true</p> :
       [condition4]
        ? <p>If condition4 is true</p> :
        null
      }
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and that's one of the reasons behind the proposal and existence of the *do expression*; it will make multiple conditional expressions syntactical friendly:

```
export default function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {do {
        if ([condition1]) <p>If condition1 is true</p>
        if ([condition2]) <p>If condition2 is true</p>
        if ([condition3]) <p>If condition3 is true</p>
        if ([condition4]) <p>If condition4 is true</p>
      } ?? null}
      <p>I am always rendered</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is no longer true in the latest version of the do expressions [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions#limitations), and explicitly writing `else` is more readable anyway. But this answer is a great explanation of why you'd want to use a do expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply, using conditioanl rendering:

```
    {condition && jsx-element}
```

Example:

```
    {relationshipStatus===RelationshipStatus.SINGLE && <ShowIAmSingleComponent />}
```

Whenever this `relationshipStatus` takes value of `RelationshipStatus.SINGLE`, it will render this `ShowIAmSingleComponent` component.

**Simple as react.**