# can I use `else if` with a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I only use `if` and `else` in a statement in ternary operator syntax or can I also somehow include an `else if`?

example:

```
if(a) {
   x
}
else if(y) {
   c
}
else {
   b
}
```

Comment: please add the code fragment as well.

Comment: Please show example of what you are trying to accomplish. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526739/a-somewhat-painful-triple-nested-ternary-operator a very bad idea anyway

Comment: No need for a code fragment or MCVE here. This is a simple factual question about syntax.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Unlike an `if` with optional `else` or optional `else if` branches, a ternary operator has two and only two branches.

It's actually a part of the name. Where `+` in `a + b` is a *binary* operator, that is it has two [operands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand#Arity), `?` has three, as in `a ? b : c`, and is termed *ternary* because of that. Technically there could be other ternary operators beyond `?` but in most languages they don't exist, so it is generally understood that the name "ternary" means the `?` operator.

You can have `else if` like functionality if you sub-branch the second clause:

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

**This is usually a bad idea** as ternary operations can be messy to start with and layering like this is usually an express train to unmaintainable code.

It is much better to write:

```
if (a) {
  b
}
else if (c) {
{
  d
}
else {
  e
}
```

This is more verbose, but abundantly clear.

If you use ternaries too agressively you'll end up with code like:

```
a()?c?d?e:f:g:h?i(j?k:l?m:n):o
```

Where it's anyone's guess what's going on in there.

Comment: parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: @NinaScholz They're necessary to illustrate the structure more clearly. Without them it turns into a mysterious mess of symbols.

Comment: Basically it works because `if(a){b}elseif(c){d}else{e}` is equal to `if(a){b}else{ if(c){d}else{e} }`

Comment: @JonasW. Precisely. `else if` is just short-hand syntax for `else { if { ... }}`

Answer (score 9):

It's very much possible!
You could use this:

```
a ? b : b ? c : d
```

Answer (score 2):

You could stack multiple ternaries:

```
var x = (y) ? 1 : ( (z) ? 2 : 0 );
```