# Ternary Condition for if { } else if { if { } else { } }

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary

I want to change all the `if` `else` statements to ternary operator. Whats the ternary operator for this `if` `else` statements ?

```
  const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
        // Update Text
        const winner = document.querySelector('.winner');
        const winnerIs = (who, isPlayerWin) => {

            winner.textContent = `${who} Wins!`;

            isPlayerWin ? pScore++ : cScore++;

            updateScore();
        };



        // Check for tie
        if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
            winner.textContent = 'It Is A Tie!';
            // Check For Winner
        } else if (playerChoice === 'rock') {
            if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                winnerIs('Player', true);
            } else {
                winnerIs('Computer', false);
            }
        } else if (playerChoice === 'paper') {
            if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                winnerIs('Computer', false);
            } else {
                winnerIs('Player', true);
            }
        } else if (playerChoice === 'scissors') {
            if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                winnerIs('Computer', false);
            } else {
                winnerIs('Player', true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use either the conditional operator *or* if-else - I'd prefer an array instead, and compare indicies

Comment: Try look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126232/can-i-use-else-if-with-a-ternary-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. Though readability is a problem since there are too many nested `if else` which is replaced by ternary operator. `true` & `false` are replace with `!0` & `!1`  respectively to shorten the statement

```js
playerChoice === computerChoice ?
  winner.textContent = "It Is A Tie!" :
  "rock" === playerChoice ?
  "scissors" === computerChoice ?
  winnerIs("Player", !0) :
  winnerIs("Computer", !1) :
  "paper" === playerChoice ?
  "scissors" === computerChoice ?
  winnerIs("Computer", !1) :
  winnerIs("Player", !0) :
  "scissors" === playerChoice && ("rock" === computerChoice ? winnerIs("Computer", !1) :
    winnerIs("Player", !0));
```

Comment: @AKX there is always a better way than the best. I just answered the question which the SO user asked. I could have suggest him object mapping instead of nested if.. else which people have already done , but that not the answer to his question

Comment: @brk Yeah, I didn't mean it as criticism – you do answer the OP's question, it's just that no one should really do this in "production" :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think the use of ternary operator will make the code better.
I suggest the you try to reduce the if-else chain by creating a data structure for easy look up, something like this:

```
const whatBeats = {
  'scissors': 'rock',
  'paper': 'scissors',
  'rock': 'paper'
};
const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  // Update Text
  const winner = document.querySelector('.winner');
  const winnerIs = (who, isPlayerWin) => {

    winner.textContent = `${who} Wins!`;

    isPlayerWin ? pScore++ : cScore++;

    updateScore();
  };

  // Check for tie
  if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
    winner.textContent = 'It Is A Tie!';
    // Check For Winner
  } else if (playerChoice === whatBeats[computerChoice]) {
    winnerIs('Player', true);
  } else {
    winnerIs('Computer', false)
  }
}
```

In this case, we are treating the game dynamics as data, centralizing it on one place.

For the next questions, try to solve the problem before (there are tons of tutorial regarding ternary operators).

Answer (score 0):

As Nina Scholz says, I would not use either. I know this does not answer the literal question, but how about this instead?

```
const loser_to = {
  paper: 'rock',
  rock: 'scissors',
  scissors: 'paper'
};

if (loser_to[playerChoice] === computerChoice) {
  // player wins
} else if (loser_to[computerChoice] === playerChoice) {
  // computer wins
} else {
  // noone wins
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using too many ternary could lead to unreadable code. I suggest you can use switch case combining with ternary operators.

```
switch (playerChoice) {
   case computerChoice: winner.textContent = 'It Is A Tie!';break;
   case 'rock': computerChoice === 'scissors' ?  winnerIs('Player', true) : winnerIs('Computer', false); break;
   case 'paper': computerChoice === 'rock' ?  winnerIs('Player', true) : winnerIs('Computer', false); break;
   case 'scissors': computerChoice === 'paper' ?  winnerIs('Player', true) : winnerIs('Computer', false); break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a much more DRYied code. You could try this solution to avoid multiple call of `winnerIs` function.

```
const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  const winner = document.querySelector('.winner');

  if (playerChoice == computerChoice) {
    winner.textContent = 'It Is A Tie!';
    return;
  }

  let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
  let playerIndex, computerIndex, isPlayerWin;

  playerIndex = choices.indexOf(playerChoice);
  choices.push(choices.shift());
  computerIndex = choices.indexOf(computerChoice);
  isPlayerWin = playerIndex !== computerIndex;

  winner.textContent = `${isPlayerWin ? 'Player' : 'Computer'} Wins!`;
  isPlayerWin ? pScore++ : cScore++;
  updateScore();
}
```