# Calling a function inside a switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to convert the following if, else if, else to a switch statement.

```
    if(zipValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(zip, 'Please enter a zip code');
} else if (!isZip(zipValue)) {
    setErrorFor(zip, 'Not a valid Aust zip code');
} else {
    setSuccessFor(zip);
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
switch (zipValue) {
case "":
setErrorFor(zip, 'Please enter a zip code');
break;
case !isZip(zipValue): //can't get this working
setErrorFor(zip, 'Not a valid Aust zip code');
break;
default:
setSuccessFor(zip);
break;
```

}

the function isZip checks against a regex as shown here:

```
function isZip(zip) {
 return /^[0-9]{4}$/.test(zip);
 }
```

The original if, else if, else is working I just want to learn more about using a switch statement and make my code cleaner. Thank you.

PS after posting this I now see the irony that the switch statement is using more lines of code.

Comment: `switch` compares the value of the supplied expression against the case values using a strict comparison (===), here you are comparing against a string in the first case and a boolean in the second so one of them will never match depending on the type of the initial `zipValue`.

Comment: I could try something like ternary with conditional chains.

Comment: Yes, you can try ternary where you return a value instead of boolean for comparison with the zipValue from the switch. Then it'll work.

Comment: I found this about using daisy chained ternary:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49762262/12822663

I have already used one ternary in my program as follows:


!terms.checked ? setErrorFor(terms, 'Please agree to the terms') : setSuccessFor(terms);

Comment: Why are you trying to change this code? The code is already in a clear and readable form. You seem to be deliberately butchering it... why?

Comment: Sometimes to have to break something that is working in order to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the case statement for !isZip(zipValue) is always going to return a boolean. I’m guessing that zipValue will always be a string. Therefore that case statement will never be run since you’re comparing two values of two different data types. So if someone inputs a zip code let’s say 12345, then when it gets to that case block it will return false. And 12345 does not equal false