# Javascript: ask for a numeric value input, give different answers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

**QUICK UPDATE!**

I may have fixed it. Now the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rangeAnswers() {
    var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?")
    if (answer > 0 )

            confirm("That's a bit low")
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";


        if (answer > 20 )

            confirm("Quite a decent score, isn't it?")
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";

    }
</script>
```

And it works. At this point i think that if i put other if's at the end for <0 or > 100 i can prompt the error message and without linking to the page in that two little if's i stay on the page right?

---

First off let me tell you i just started with js so this may be a bit dumb.

Here's what i need to do. I have a normal HTML link with a function called on click which asks the user something like "How much do you like pizza(0 100)?".

The user types in a number and i want different answers, which will still direct you to the link anyway(so no controls to send back the user here) based on the number he wrote.

I want four major breakpoints at 0-25, 26-50, 51-75, 71-100 ELSE(lower or higher value) it just alerts("The number you specified is invalid") and stays in the page so the user can click again and put a correct value(nothing fancy then).

The thing i want when he inserts a correct value is let's say 0-25 "You don't like it very much", 26-50 "Not good but not bad" etcetera + the link.

Here's my HTML a:

```
<h2><a href="javascript:rangeAnswers();">Click here to tell us how much you like pizza and continue!</a></h2>
```

And here's the foundation of my Javascript function which is NOT loading! I tried a simple Ok/cancel prompt and it worked but i still can't get the logic of if/else statement.
**THIS IS THE OLD CODE, I RE-PASTED THE CORRECT ONE!**
    
        function rangeAnswers() {
        var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?")
        if (answer) > 0

```
        {
            alert= "That's a bit low"
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";
        }    else

            if (answer) > 20

        {
            alert= "You don't like it nor hate it"
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";
        } else

    }
</script>
```

I think that's all for now, i'm still trying to work on this while i'm waiting for replies but it's been a while now and i can't get what i'm missing.

**HERE'S THE UPDATED WORKING CODE**

It doesn't load my alert/prompts though.

```
function rangeAnswers() {
    var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?")
    if (answer > 0 )

            alert= "Nice!"
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";


        if (answer > 20 )

            alert= "Nice!"
            window.location="http://www.continue.com";

    }
```

Comment: Pleas add all your source code... or is this all you've got?

Comment: Try to open developer console in browser like firebug in firefox or developers tools in chrome...

Comment: use the console in your browser to find and fix all syntax errors, e.g. `if (answer > 0)` instead of `if (answer) > 0`

Comment: I've already corrected the syntax errors with the debugger because as i said i'm new to js.

And yes, this is all i got. It's a test page so i only have the h1 with a title and the h2 with a link, plus the little function which is not working.

Comment: Add some information about files structure...

Comment: Damiano the file structure is irrelevant i think, i just have a single empty page with an h1, an h2 and the function call on the a inside the h2. Nothing more nothing less, no other js or anything else.

Comment: @daghene it's good to show it anyways. The shorter the better, as long as it still demonstrates the issue. see http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t isn't loading because you have a trailing else, and you had parantheses around the answers, but not around the whole Booleans. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rangeAnswers(){
        var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?");
        if (answer > 0) {
            alert("Nice!");
            window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";
        }else if (answer > 20){
            alert("Nice!");
            window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDITED - full version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rangeAnswers(){
        var answer, 
            bad=false;
        while(true){
            answer = prompt('How much do you like pizza?');
            if(isNaN(answer)){
                bad=true;
            }else{
                bad=false;
                answer = parseInt(answer,10);
                if(answer>100 || answer<0){
                    bad=true;
                }else if(answer===100){
                    alert('Wow, you REALLY love pizza!');
                }else if (answer >= 75) {
                    alert('75-99!');
                }else if (answer >= 50){
                    alert('50-74');
                }else if (answer >= 25){
                    alert('25-49');
                }else{
                    alert('0-24');
                }
                if(!bad){
                    window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";
                    return;
                }
            }
            if(bad){
                alert('I need a number between 0 and 100!');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually fixed the code here and in the main post.

It works but doesn't display my alert/prompts!

Comment: To get the alerts, you needed `alert('text');` because it is a function call, and functions use those parantheses.

Comment: Now it works, thank you! I've updated the code to the top with one last question, which is for the incorrect values (less than zero, more than 100).

Answer (score 0):

Your html should looks like this

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2><a href="javascript:rangeAnswers();">Click here to tell us how much you like pizza and continue!</a></h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code

```
 function rangeAnswers() {
        var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?")       
       if (answer<=25 && answer =>0){
            alert("That's a bit low")//you are not alerting your data properly.
            window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";//use window.location.href instead of window.location
       }
        else if (answer<=50 && answer =>25){
             alert("You don't like it nor hate it")
            window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
Other way to do the same thing would be by using the **switch** case:

```
function rangeAnswers() {
            var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?") 
    switch(true){
          case answer<=25 && answer =>0:
                alert("That's a bit low")//you are not alerting your data properly.
                window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";//use window.location.href instead of window.location
           break;
           case answer<=50 && answer =>25:
                 alert("You don't like it nor hate it")
                window.location.href="http://www.continue.com";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That switch statement is incorrect. `answer <= 25 && answer >= 0` only equals `answer` if answer is `true`. Your "greater than or equals" operator is incorrect as well

Comment: @JanDvorak:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464362/javascript-using-a-condition-in-switch-case

Comment: you can't expect the question to have correct code. [See the top voted answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9055603/499214)

Comment: `switch(true)` instead of `switch(answer)` will produce functional code. Not sure if I like that pattern, however.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34221/discussion-between-messiah-and-jan-dvorak)

Answer (score 0):

I think  the incorrect grammar made your process not going:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rangeAnswers() {

    var answer = prompt ("How much do you like pizza?");
    answer = answer - 0;
    if(isNaN(answer))
    {
        alert("The number you specified is invalid");
    }else if (answer >= 0 && answer <=25)
    {
         alert("You don't like it very much");
         window.location="http://www.continue.com";
    }else if (answer > 25 && answer <=50)
    {
        alert("Not good but not bad");
        window.location="http://www.continue.com";
    } 
    //and so on ....
}
</script>
```