# switch case redirect by geolocation latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I want to redirect by geolocation and i try with this javascript function and it works fine:

```
 function showPosition(pos)
  {

   if (pos.coords.latitude >= 10.4696404 && pos.coords.longitude <= -66.8037185)
        {
            window.location = 'http://www.website.com/page1.html';
        }
        else{
            window.location = 'http://www.website.com/page2.html';
        }
  }
```

but when i try to use a switch case do not work, what is wrong here?

```
function showPosition(pos)
      {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        switch(lat + "|" + lon){
            case lat >="10.4696404"|lon <="-66.8037185"://Caracas
                window.location = 'http://www.website.com/page1.html';
            break;
            case lat >="10.0618663"|lon <="-69.3628479"://BARQUISIMETO
                window.location = 'http://www.website.com/page2.html';
            break;
            case lat >="10.6335502"|lon <="-71.6769433": //MARACAIBO
                window.location = 'http://www.website.com/page3.html';
            break;
            default
            window.location = 'http://www.website.com/';
        }
      }
```

Comment: Could it be that you're comparing a with a number in the first example and a string in the second? Are lat and lon strings or numbers?

Comment: Hi lat and lot are the values of geolocation position its something like lat=10.4696404 and lon=-66.8037185

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:` after `default`:

```
...
  default:
    window.location = 'http://www.website.com/';
...
```

UPDATE:

Check the javascript switch sintax, maybe this question could help you: [javascript: using a condition in switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464362/javascript-using-a-condition-in-switch-case)

Comment: @VirgilioCalderon I updated my answer, check the link that could help you