# Javascript/JQuery/AJAX Else If not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First off, I am a beginner.  I am trying to find a solution to my problem.  Basically I want my text to be a different color based on a number so I used a ELSE IF statement.  It works, but it doesn't and I tried 2 different ways.  I used an API for the basic display of the numbers (temperatures from sensors)

See JFiddle for examples it also displays the rest of the code displaying the number.

http://jsfiddle.net/1brkww9h/98/

```
if (templr < 60) {
$("#displaylr").css("color", "#0000ff");
}
    else    if (templr < 70 && templr > 69) {
$("#displaylr").css("color", "#FFED00");
} else if (templr < 69 && templr > 68) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#FFFC00");
} else if (templr < 68 && templr > 67) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#EBEE12");
} else if (templr < 67 && templr > 66) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#CFD42C");
} else if (templr < 66 && templr > 65) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#ABB24A");
} else if (templr < 65 && templr > 64) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#858C6C");
} else if (templr < 64 && templr > 63) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#3D41AF");
} else if (templr < 63 && templr > 62) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#0000FD");
} else if (templr < 62 && templr > 61) {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#424DFF");
} else {
    $("#displaylr").css("color", "#dddddd");

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1brkww9h/99/

```
if (templr < 1) {
   $("#displaylr").css("color", "#000000");
}
else if (templr = 69) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#FFED00");
}
else if (templr = 68) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#FFFC00");
}
else if (templr = 67) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#EBEE12");
}
else if (templr = 66) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#CFD42C");
}
else if (templr = 65) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#ABB24A");
}
else if (templr = 64) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#858C6C");
}
else if (templr = 63) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#3D41AF");
}
else if (templr = 62) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#0000FD");
}
else if (templr = 61) {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#424DFF");
}
else {
  $("#displaylr").css("color", "#dddddd");

}
```

Comment: You wrote "It works, but it doesn't". Sorry, what is it that you want to appear? What is appearing that you don't want to appear?

Comment: Please use [Switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) Statement.

Comment: @Kirby It's changing the color, but it's not changing it based on the number...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki How do I use the switch statement with else ifs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464362/javascript-using-a-condition-in-switch-case/9055603#9055603

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Now nothing displays using CASE.

http://jsfiddle.net/1brkww9h/104/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `templr` variable is a jQuery object and not a number.

`jObject.text(var)` would return `jObject` and `jObject.text()` would return text inside `jObject`.

You need to change your code

```
var templr = $("#displaylr").text(((retval.d.temp_degC * 1.8) + 32).toFixed(1));
```

to

```
var templr = (retval.d.temp_degC * 1.8) + 32;
$("#displaylr").text(templr.toFixed(1));
```

Also your conditions in `if` statements newer match whole numbers, only in between.

Numbers `65` and `64` will get `#dddddd`, but numbers 64.1 to 64.9 will get `#858C6C`.

If you just want a blue-yellow gradient between 60 and 70, you can use this function

```
function get_color(num, min_val, min_color, max_val, max_color)
{
    if (num <= min_val)
        return "rgb("+min_color.join(",")+")";
    if (num >= max_val)
        return "rgb("+max_color.join(",")+")";
    var t = (num-min_val)/(max_val-min_val);
    var color = [0,0,0];
    for (var j=0; j<3; j++)
        color[j] = Math.floor(min_color[j]*(1-t) + max_color[j]*t);
    return "rgb("+color.join(",")+")";
}
```

and then you can replace all the `if` statements with

```
$("#displaylr").css("color", get_color(templr, 60, [0x00,0x00,0xFF], 70, [0xFF,0xFF,0x00]));
```

Comment: AWESOME!  I tweaked a few things, but this is exactly what I needed.
@gre_gor

Comment: What if I wanted a gradient like this? http://jakerieskamp.com/mobile/colormap.html @gre_gor